# Probability and deductible

Tags: probability

For a certain health insurance policy, losses are uniformly distributed on the interval
[0, b]. The policy has a deductible of 180 and the expected value of the unreimbursed
portion of a loss is 144.

Question is on what does it mean unreimbursed portion,is that portion less than the deductible?

Comment: Say you file a claim of size $x$ (drawn uniformly from $[0,b]$).  then your payout is $\max(x-180,0)$.  Therefore, your unreimbursed loss is $x-\max(x-180,0)$.  That is a variable which you can compute the expectation of.  I assume the point is to then solve for $b$

Comment: Example:  say that $b=500$.  Then if your claim is $180≤x≤500$ your unreimbursed loss is $x-180$.  The measure here is $\frac {dx}{500}$ so the expected value of the unreimbursed loss is $\int_{180}^{500} (x-180)\frac {dx}{500}=102.4$.  (so we see that $b>500$).

Comment: Question is what have you tried in attempting to resolve this problem on your own? In addition, please spend a moment of your time in order to provide the mathematical meaning of 'The policy has a deductible' and 'unreimbursed portion'.

Answer (score 1):

Let Y'=Unreimbursed portion and X=the total loss incurred. 
Y' =144 = `X, for X<180
     or 180,for X>180.`
144 = integral of (X/b)dx+180*prb(X>180)dx with limit 0 to 180. 
prb(X>180) = (b-180)/b, this is done using CDF of the uniform distribution.

Doing the integration and evaluation gives b=450

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).